# Need some explanation about JPQL, JPA and Glassfish to persist data

Tags: jsp, jpa, jpql, persist

I'm new to JSP and here is what I want to know. I'm simply printing some data on my HTML page :

```
${movie.title}
```

I have a `Movie` Entity, and a `MovieManager` EntityManager. When I want to add a review to the movie (which is another entity, `Review`), my servlet calls this piece of code in the MovieManager :

```
Movie m = new Movie(//some data...);
em.persist(m);
```

But when I'm redirected on my page, this review is not refreshed and printed just after but I would even say maybe 30 seconds later.

I tried a lot of things I saw on the web, mainly this :

```
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

But both of them return these errors :

> Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.

And :

> EJBException, java.lang.IllegalStateException for close.

Please give me some advices of what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

A servlet is part of the presentation layer. It shouldn't deal with JPA. Instead, it should call services, implemented as EJBs and containing the business logic, which in turn should call DAOs, also implemented as EJBs, and containing the persistence logic, dealing with the entity manager.

The service EJB would start a transaction automatically each time one of its method is called (that's the main reason for using EJBs), and commit it automatically when the method returns.